# Kentico home page shows 404 but admin works fine

Tags: c#, .net, kentico

I'm new to Kentico and can't seem to get the home page to load correctly, it just returns a 404. I have a site setup in IIS and I have know the app pool has access to the database I'm using for Kentico because when I change it I do see the Kentico error page about SQL access. Once I fix SQL access and reload the page, it shows a 404 again.

For example, if I access `dev.mydomain.com` in a browser, I get the browser 404. If I access `dev.mydomain.com/admin` it takes me to the Kentico admin section correctly.

There is a site setup in the Kentico settings with the correct domain alias. I have a licence for that alias too.  All the tables in the DB appear correct.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the issue. I appears that somehow the `\CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx` file had become corrupted. I replaced that and I can now visit `dev.mydomain.com` with no problems.  Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: OMG, that's a first for me!

Comment: Same happened here, after an upgrade from 8.2 to 9.0, the PortalTemplate.aspx file was nowhere to be found. I copied manually from C:\Program Files (x86)\Kentico\9.0\Upgrade82_90\CMS\CMS\CMSPages, and all sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have the configuration in IIS setup properly.  My guess is you most likely don't have your site configured properly within Kentico.

- Do you have a home page setup in the content tree?
- Do you have the Settings>Content>Website content>Default alias path set to that home page?

If those are not configured then you will get a not found error.

Comment: Yes, I have a home page setup that has the live url set as `http://dev.mydomain.com` and alias path as `/home`.  In the settings, default alias path it is set to `/home` too

Answer (score 1):

What is the home page you have in the Pages application? For example, if the page name is "Home", then try dev.mydomain.com/home and see if you can see that page. 
If that page loads up correctly, you can go to Settings application > Settings > Content > Web site content > Default alias path, and select that page to be the Home page.
If dev.mydomain.com/home still give you 404, then there is some configuration issues.

Comment: I tried going to `dev.mydomain.com/home` and I still get a 404 unfortunately

Comment: try /home.aspx as likely you don't have extension less enabled. Also, try any page in the tree, then click on the Kentico logo, and click the "Live site" button at the lower left corner in the Applications flyout, does any page load up without 404?

Comment: Ahh, I did try with the aspx part but unfortunately the same issue.  When trying to preview the pages in the tree I instead get this message at the top: `Page is currently using Content workflow and is in Published step.`.  This isn't a fresh install of Kentico but contains some already created pages and a site plus some customizations.

Comment: Also the Live Site button gives me the same 404, just a slightly different URL of `dev.mydomain.com/?viewmode=0`

Comment: can you try to create a sample.aspx direct in Visual Studio, save that to the /CMS folder. Then browse dev.mydomain.com/sample.aspx, does it come up?

Comment: Yes, so my sample.aspx file does show correctly when I go to `dev.mydomain.com/sample.aspx`. So do you think this is a kentico site configuation problem?

Comment: try add this runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to you web.config. this is where you need to add it https://docs.kentico.com/k8/configuring-kentico/configuring-page-urls/custom-and-extensionless-urls#CustomandextensionlessURLs-ConfiguringIIStoallowcustomURLextensions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like I already have that line in the web.config file so it didn't fix the issue.